# How to pass parameter from View through Ribbon in WPF/Prism?

Tags: wpf, prism, ribbon

I did successfully place a RibbonControl into my shell-view (I'm using PRISM) and I'm also able to navigate to a different view when a Ribbon control has been clicked.

Now, I'm stuck with the following problem: how can I pass a parameter from one view to the other? I know how to do it via CommandParameter however, the problem is that I'm in the shell view model.

To be more explicit: e.g. on 1st view user selects a row from listview (containing record ID). Now, I want to click on a RibbonButton and open a 2nd view with the parameter from view 1.

Could someone point me to the right direction?

Thank you so much!

N.

Comment: You can use Navigation paramerters and use INavigationAware interface..

Comment: Show some code on how you navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IRegionManager.RequestNavigate to navigate, and then have you ViewModels implement INavigationAware.  Read the docs here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/60-Navigation.md

Answer (score 0):

Brian, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I was totally on the wrong track (looking for a way how to read & pass parameter in shell view).

And the solution is so clear and beauty:

```
public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    if (SelectedItem != null)
    {
        BGKO data = new BGKO();
        data.ID = SelectedItem.ID;
        data.NO = SelectedItem.NO;

        navigationContext.NavigationService.Region.Context = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's how Prism is used to be. Consider to accept his answer as correct.